# How to continuously resize Div to 100% VH

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/s4tzo2ms/

I want to continuously re-size div height to 100% of view height.  I can get it to set when the browser loads but I'm not sure how to always change it whenever the user changes the browser not just when the browser loads.

```js
var width = $(window).width(); 
var height=$(window).height(); 
$("#mydiv").width(width);
$("#mydiv").height(height);
```

```css
#mydiv{
  background:black;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer js over css solution, you need something like this:

```
var width = $(window).width(); 
var height=$(window).height(); 
var mydiv=$("#mydiv");
mydiv.width(width);
mydiv.height(height);

$(window).resize(function(){
  width = $(window).width();
  height=$(window).height();
  mydiv.width(width);
  mydiv.height(height);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont use, `100vh` in `height`?

```css
#mydiv{
  background:black;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: oops, missed that, for some reaosn I thought VH doesn't re-size

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rely plainly on CSS?

First remove your existing javascript, then set the width and height for the browser and mydiv to 100%, so that when you resize the screen the div will resize relatively with the parents.

```
html,body{
 height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#mydiv{
  background:black;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work because what if I have content underneath and elsewhere